# How many triples (formed by distinct numbers) are possible taken from from the set ${1,2,3,4,...30}$ such that there product is a multiple of 9.

Tags: combinatorics

***How many triples (formed by distinct numbers) are possible taken from from the set ${{1,2,3,4,...30}} $ such that their product is a multiple of*** 9.

My workout:

$\binom {30}{3}$-Choosing distinct numbers.

From here on we have to make the sum of the number equal to 9 or its multiple.

I got that part only.How should i proceed from here.

I also tried taking cases like when sum=9,sum=18,sum=27 and so on but it became too long and i had to give up.(here sum = sum of the digits of the product of the number)

Comment: How about counting triples whose product is not a multiple of $9$?

Comment: thought of that but could not proceed in the examination hall

Comment: Use the hint that either two of those numbers should have a power of 3 or atleast one of them should be a multiple of 9.

Comment: Product or Sum?

Comment: product........

Comment: @dp1611 Ok, I didn't notice "(here sum = sum of the digits of the product of the number)".

Comment: @dp1611 Well, how about (i) counting those triples whose product is not a multiple of 3, (ii) those triples whose product is a multiple of 3 but not of 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lord shark shows in comments, you take two cases:

1. The prod is multiple of $3$ but not $9$. Choose $2$ nums from $20$ non-multiples of $3$ and $1$ num from $(10-3)$ multiples of $3$ but not $9$. This can be done in $\binom{20}{2}\binom{7}{1}$ ways.
2. The prod is not multiple of $3$. Choose $3$ nums from $20$ non-multiples of $3$. Can be done in $\binom{20}{3}$ ways.

Thus you have the answer as $\binom{30}{3}-\binom{20}{2}\binom{7}{1} - \binom{20}{3}$

Comment: $=1590$, matches with my brute force calculation.

Comment: @ploosu2 Thank you a lot for verifying!